# "Check the render method of" react native error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, formik, yup

I know this question has been asked a lot but non of the solutions on them solve my problem. I get this problem when rendering a specific component in my App file which is the "ListingEditScreen" which is a form and the error I have says

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to
> export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of `ListingEditScreen`.

My code is as follows

```js
import React from "react";
import ListingEditScreen from "./app/screens/ListingEditScreen";

export default function App() {
  return <ListingEditScreen />;
}
```

And then this is my ListingEditScreen

```js
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import {
  AppForm,
  AppFormField,
  AppFormPicker,
  SubmitButton,
} from "../components/forms";
import Screen from "../components/Screen";

const validationSchema = {
  title: Yup.string().required().min(1).label("Title"),
  price: Yup.number().required().min(1).max(10000).label("Price"),
  description: Yup.string().label("Description"),
  category: Yup.string().required().nullable().label("Category"),
};

const categories = [
  {
    id: 1,
    label: "Furniture",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    label: "Electronics",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    label: "Clothing",
  },
];

export default function ListingEditScreen() {
  return (
    <Screen style={styles.container}>
      <AppForm
        initialValues={{
          title: "",
          price: "",
          description: "",
          category: null,
        }}
        onSubmit={(values) => console.log(values)}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
      >
        <AppFormField maxLength={255} name="title" placeholder="Title" />
        <AppFormField
          maxLength={8}
          name="price"
          placeholder="Price"
          keyboardType="numeric"
        />
        <AppFormPicker
          items={categories}
          name="category"
          placeholder="Category"
        />
        <AppFormField
          maxLength={255}
          multiline
          numberOfLines={3}
          name="description"
          placeholder="Description"
        />
        <SubmitButton title="Post" />
      </AppForm>
    </Screen>
  );
}
```

So where could I be going wrong because from the other questions it seems to be an import issue but I have checked all my imports and they seem fine so what could be the problem thanks in advance.

Edit: The problem seems to be in the AppFormPicker and here is the code below. Firstly, this is my forms folder index.js

```
export {default as AppForm} from "./AppForm"
export {default as AppFormField} from "./AppFormField"
export {default as AppFormPicker} from "./AppFormPicker"
export {default as FormError} from "./FormError"
export {default as SubmitButton} from "./SubmitButton"
```

And then followed by the AppFormPicker component

```js
import React from "react";
import { useFormikContext } from "formik";
import { FormError } from "./FormError";
import AppPicker from "../AppPicker";

export default function AppFormPicker({ items, name, placeholder }) {
  const { errors, setFieldValue, touched, values } = useFormikContext();

  return (
    <>
      <AppPicker
        items={items}
        onSelectItem={(item) => setFieldValue(name, item)}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        selectedItem={values[name]}
      />
      <FormError error={errors[name]} visible={touched[name]} />
    </>
  );
}
```

My file structure is like this app⬇components⬇forms⬇➡AppForm.js,AppFormField.js,AppFormPicker.js,FormError.js,SubmitButton.js

This is the error in its entirety on the debugger[image]

Comment: Can you put here the complete error itself? It ll help in debugging

Comment: @ShivamJha sure I have updated

Comment: Why you need to import the `import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'` (in the first code block)?

Comment: @hisam I just didnt copy the stylesheet assumed it isnt necessary let me remove it

Comment: Have you tried to add `{}`?  So the import statement would be like `import { ListingEditScreen } from './app/screens/ListingEditScreen'`.

Comment: @hisam i have and now it has changed to 
Check the render method of `App`.

Comment: @Vuyi could you attach a screenshot of the error in `Debugger`. Because one of these is `Undefined`.
AppForm, AppFormField, AppFormPicker, SubmitButton, Screen

Comment: @FnH I dont really know how to use debugger I am still learning now and on the vscode documentation its quite a long read but the culprit is more likely to be the AppFormPicker. I noticed that I had not exported it on my index.js file and now that I have, it is saying check the render method of AppFormPicker. I have updated my code to its at the end. I think the problem lies there

Comment: @Vuyi It is easy to activate [https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging](https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging) just follow this.

Comment: @Vuyi In shot if you are using a Device just `Shake Left-Right` a few times or in the case of simulator `⌘D` for MAC & `Ctrl+M` for Windows/Linux. You will  see [this](https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/17d866dec23b0d7748d6ce868cda68db7d4e4a8c/070f1/assets/images/developermenu-f22b01f374248b3242dfb3a1017f98a8.png).
Then Select `Debug JS Remotely`

Then a `crome` page will be opened just `inspected` that and open `console` tab.

Comment: @FnH I am using my mobile device and when I shake, the options with the debugger only open when there's no error like when I render out other components with no errors but when I restart the app rendering the ListingEditScreen where there's the error, the debugging options are not accessible but I have put a screenshot in the original post of the debugger

Comment: Was this supposed to be a typo in AppFormPiciers definition? "return (
    <>...". Because that being empty isn't right and sounds like it could be the culprit. You probably want to change it to be "<React.Fragment>". This is essentially reacts way of grouping two components together as if you wanted them to travel together but you don't want to manipulate them graphically (i.e. you don't want to use a View or something like that). I'll put a better post in the comments to say this better..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AppFormPicker's definition:

try changing:

```
return (
    <>
      <AppPicker
        items={items}
        onSelectItem={(item) => setFieldValue(name, item)}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        selectedItem={values[name]}
      />
      <FormError error={errors[name]} visible={touched[name]} />
    </>
  );
```

to be:

```
return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <AppPicker
        items={items}
        onSelectItem={(item) => setFieldValue(name, item)}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        selectedItem={values[name]}
      />
      <FormError error={errors[name]} visible={touched[name]} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
```

I suspect the error message is seeing <> as a component whose name is undefined. In that, you literally have no component name there.